# How to make a user sign out in Firebase?

Tags: android, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am making a simple authentication app in Android using Firebase authentication. Till now I am successful in signing the user in, however the issue is that the user remains signed in, and I can't find a way to sign him out.

Here is my MainActivity.java code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //tracking the sign in and singn out operations
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user!=null){
                    System.out.println("User logged in");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("User not logged in");
                }
            }
        };
    }


    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
    public void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);

        }
    }


    public void buttonClicked(View view){

        EditText editemail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        EditText editpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        String email = editemail.getText().toString();
        String password = editpass.getText().toString();


        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                     //   Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication Success.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Success.class));
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                           // Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }



}
```

Comment: I think You need to call "unauth()"  immediately deletes that token from local storage because when you call firebase authentication it keeps the token for that particular user in local storage on device.In recent time "signOut" took the place of "unauth" and it's look like deprecated.

Comment: Thanks @AbuSufian, I placed the "FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();" in onStop method and it works.

Comment: @SuzanCruz Would you mind selecting a "correct answer". There are a few duplicates and your selecting one to be Green would help us not need to read them all.

Comment: this might help:https://stackoverflow.com/a/56338259/6738361

Answer (score 55):

Use this code `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();`

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I put this code   FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();" in my onStop method. Hopefully thats the correct way td do so.

Comment: How can I sign back in with a different user? The old user persists when I log back in

Answer (score 34):

You can simply call this

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

If you want to perform some action after sign out then use this one.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.sign_out) {
        AuthUI.getInstance()
            .signOut(this)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    // user is now signed out
                    startActivity(new Intent(MyActivity.this, SignInActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: in order to add the .addOnCompleteListener for signOut you need to implement Firebase UI like the docs on github states "The entry point to the authentication flow is the com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI class."  Latest versions here https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md#configuration

Answer (score 15):

This can be solved by using [AuthStateListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener)

```
//Declaration and defination
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){
            //Do anything here which needs to be done after signout is complete
            signOutComplete();
        }
        else {
        }
    }
};

//Init and attach
firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener);

//Call signOut()
firebaseAuth.signOut();
```

Snippet : https://codepad.co/snippet/aPeehdoD

Answer (score 13):

Firebase auth is provide signout method.

```
 FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I put this code   FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();" in my onStop method. Hopefully thats the correct way td do so.

Answer (score 8):

Try This

```
FirebaseAuth fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
 fAuth.signOut();
```

Comment: unless you need `fAuth` for something else, `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();` works just fine

Answer (score 6):

if you are using [firebaseAuthUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) then recommended method is

```
public void onClick(View v) {
if (v.getId() == R.id.sign_out) {
    AuthUI.getInstance()
        .signOut(this)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                // user is now signed out
                startActivity(new Intent(MyActivity.this, SignInActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

according to firebaseAuthUI [github Guide](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md).

Answer (score 3):

use this`

```
findViewById(R.id.signout).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            Intent intent = new Intent(currentActivity.this, MainActivity.class);             

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);//makesure user cant go back
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });`
```

Answer (score 3):

```
logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
  firebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
  Intent intent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this,SignInActivity.class);
  startActivity(intent);
  }
});
```

Comment: Make sure you add the following before onCreate method:                                              private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

Answer (score 2):

This one just signs you out from the current application .

if you are using a fragment do this

```
AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(getActivity());
```

if you are using an activity do this

```
AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(getApplicationContext);
```

**cheers**!

Answer (score 1):

For complete log out I would recommend :

```
mFirebaseAuth.signOut();
Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);
```

Answer (score 0):

There have several way to sign out user:

**1. FirebaseUI:** [Refarence](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md)

*Add depenencies:*

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.0.0'
}
```

Then:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
if (v.getId() == R.id.sign_out) {
    AuthUI.getInstance()
        .signOut(this)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                // user is now signed out
                startActivity(new Intent(MyActivity.this, SignInActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

**2. Kotlin:** [Referance](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth)

*Use Android default Authentication dependency, ex:* `com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1`

```
firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
  // Sign-out successful.
}).catch(function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});
```

---

**3. Default with java:**

*Use Android default Authentication dependency, ex:* `com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1`

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
try {
     mAuth.signOut();
     Toast.makeText(this, "User Sign out!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}catch (Exception e) {
     Log.e(TAG, "onClick: Exception "+e.getMessage(),e );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

Then, to detect the sign-in status:

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
public static boolean mAuthSignIn() {
    if (mAuth != null) {
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        return user != null;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this one it is working for me.

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        .signOut(this)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                // user is now signed out
                startActivity(new Intent(YOUR CURRENT ACTIVITY, ACTIVITY IN WHICH YOU WANT TO MOVE));
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Comment: # Khyati Fataniai don't think that you ever tried the above code mentioned in my reply.
otherwise you will not say like this .


i my self tried this one in my live app which is completely built on firebase .

Comment: I have tried your code, but it shows error on signOut method