# FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut() doesn't signout

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I try to signout user from firebase but after i close my app and open again the user is stills connect

I tried the regular signout of user from firebase and it not solve the problem.
I am wondering what could cause the problem

```java
 logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                Intent picture_intent = new Intent(Dashboard.this,LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(picture_intent );
            }
        });
```

my check if user connect:

```
@Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        FirebaseUser currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(currentUser != null)
        {
            SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            int again = preferences.getInt(String.valueOf(R.string.remember_me), 0);
            if(again == 0)
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PagerActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Dashboard.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you check if user is logged in?

Comment: Is there a FirebaseUI-Android library in your project?

Comment: I did not have FirebaseUI-Android library, I don't need this for my app. i will check about the smartlock but I dont think that is the problem, maybe try on diffrent phone would help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are being logged out correctly but as you are moving to

> LoginActivity.class

Where you might be logging the user back in again you would have to make certain changes in Login activity.

Answer (score 2):

Why you are using SharedPreferences? If you are maintaining the session with firebase you don't need sharedpreferences. 
By the way your code seems correct. Try doing the following modification with your intent after calling the logout function.

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();    
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

And completely delete your **onAuthStateChanged()** method (Because I cannot see your complete code, and may be you are messing the things inside this method) so just for testing remove this method, and add the flags to your intent as I said.

If it is working let me know.

Hope this will help you. Thanks

Comment: thank you it work for me, i the mistake was in the login as you said.